# Global namespace vars?

Tags: javascript, jquery, namespaces

I am trying to do something like

```
(function( skillet, $, undefined ) {

skillet.global = {

   names: { 

      first: 'abe',
      last: 'watson'

   },
   addresses: {
      home: 'blah'
   }

}

}( window.skillet = window.skillet || {}, jQuery ));
```

So that I can access like

```
skillet.global.names.first();
skillet.global.address.home();
```

But I keep getting errors ? How can I go about fixing this

Comment: first and home are not methods...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are calling `first` and `home` as if they were functions; yet you have defined them as object properties.

Calling `skillet.global.names.first` would (if in  an alert) show `abe`, if you need to define  them in functions, you need to use the correct function declaration, i.e.

```
   names: { 
      first: function() {
          return 'abe';
      },
      last: 'watson'
   },
   addresses: {
      home: function() {
          return 'blah';
      }
   }
```

Comment: *"...yet you have defined them as object types"* No, he's defined them as object *properties*. Strings, in this case. He also used `address` in one place but `addresses` in another.

Comment: thanks for the response. so I should be using `skillet.global.names.first;` i.e. I didnt want to use them as functions but as variables ? How would I structure it so that I can define them as variables ?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, updated, Andy, by not appending the extra `()`, to turn it into a function call.

Comment: @Andy: epoch's answer shows how to make them functions. (One way, anyway.)

Comment: haha yep - my mistake :P. still learning about namespaces so a bit confused how it all works :) thanks heaps

Comment: @epoch @T.J.Crowder - sorry one more question. what if I wanted to reference the `names` property in the `addresses` object ? would it be like `addresses: { home: 'blah', additional: skillet.global.names.first }` ?

Answer (score 3):

change `skillet.global.names.first();` to `skillet.global.names.first;`

change `skillet.global.address.home();` to `skillet.global.addresses.home;`